# When "if else"/"instance of" are inevitable, how do we improve the design apart from using visitor pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, instanceof, visitor-pattern, liskov-substitution-principle

When we have an object hierarchy that is purely a inheritance of semantic and not of behaviors,then inevitably we need to write "instanceof" or "if/else" everywhere to do run time type checking.

E.g.

If I have a object hierarchy which has

```
Class Function

Class Average extends Function

Class Sum extends Function

Class Max extends Function
```

If there is a method called calculate() in these classes, then we do not have problem, we can just take the advantage of polymorphism and this design satisfies the LSP.

However what if we do not want to add this calculate() method to this hierarchy for some reason, these objects are purely plain object stateless objects just represent the semantic.

Then we are forced to write the following code everywhere :

```
if (function instanceof Average)
//perform average
else if(function instanceof Sum)
//perform sum
else if(function instanceof Max)
//perform max
```

The code above indicates a bad design, because you write this code everywhere and this design is fragile and is hard to change later on. I guess if the number functions are limited and the calculation of function are in a single place this perhaps is ok depends on the complexity.

What I've known so far is that to solve above approach, the only possible way is to implement a visitor pattern, is there any other way to solve the above design apart from using visitor pattern?

One problem I can see from visitor pattern is that visitor pattern's accept method does not return value, this is not convenient sometime if the accept() method doesn't fully satisfy the requirement.

Comment: what about the strategy pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern ?

Comment: don't think strategy will work, please check my comments below

Comment: hmmm okay. But if those if-elseif-else blocks are everywhere in your project it might work to refactor that block out into a separate utility method

Comment: So looks like there is no easy way to implement a better design for this ? and if/else branching is inevitable?

Comment: looks like it as long as your stuck with this unless you can change the code of you `Function` class

Comment: Why exactly can't you use the Visitor pattern?

Comment: I can use it, but I prefer to have a better alternative, also because its accept() method doesn't return value, this is inconvenient as you have to downcast the visitor class to call its specific method.

Answer (score 4):

If you still know the types at compile time you can use a helper class:

```
class Function {
}

class Average extends Function {
}

class Sum extends Function {
}

class Max extends Function {
}

class FunctionHelper {
  public Number calculate(Average a) {
    return null;
  }

  public Number calculate(Sum s) {
    return null;
  }

  public Number calculate(Max a) {
    return null;
  }

  public Number calculate(Function a) {
    return null;
  }

}
```

Generally you'd make the helper methods static but you are not restricted to that - there are some rather interesting things you can do with multiple flavours of helper class.

Comment: That is a bit of a dangerous approach, as it relies on compile-time dispatch. And what is the last method (with Function) going to do other than the same instanceof we want to avoid.

Comment: @Thilo - I wouldn't call it dangerous - I did note that you must know the types at compile time. The last `Function` implementation is the equivalent of a default, perhaps it will `return 0;`.

Comment: So this will return 0:  `Function x = new Sum(); calculate(x);` and this will not: `Sum x = new Sum(); calculate(x); `.

Comment: @Thilo - correct. And thus my comment *If you still know the types at compile time...*

Comment: If you have that kind of compile-time coupling, you don't need any marker objects at all. You can just have a method `calculate_sum()` and a method `calculate_max()`. The only reason I can see for these Function objects (that don't have state or behaviour) is to be able to switch on them at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

> these objects are purely plain object stateless objects just represent the semantic.

Sounds like you want to use enums then instead of regular objects.

Then you can use `switch` statements and have the compiler check that you handled all cases.

```
enum Function { Average, Sum, Max }
```

Comment: In my opinion it doesn't solve a problem since you still need to perform switching and it is highly unscaleable.

Comment: @MichalBorek: Without any methods on the Functions, how are you going to avoid switching?

Comment: You could also add `calculate` methods to the enums.

Comment: yes. But OP does not want methods (for some unknown reason). And if method obviate switching (which they should), there is no more need for enums.

Answer (score 0):

i just stumbled over the [Chain of Responsibilty pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/chain-of-responsibility-pattern.html) which might solve your Problem:

For this we create a handler class for every Function starting with a common base class

```
public abstract class FunctionHandler {
    private FunctionHandler nexthandler = null;

    protected abstract boolean isConditionMet(Function function);

    protected abstract void calculate(Function function);

    public void handleFunction(Function function) {
        if(function == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (isConditionMet(function)) {
            calculate(function);
        } else {
            if (nexthandler != null) {
                nexthandler.handleFunction(function);
            }
        }
    }

    public FunctionHandler setNexthandler(FunctionHandler nexthandler) {
        this.nexthandler = nexthandler;
        return nexthandler;
    }
}
```

next we create the concrete handlers:

```
public class Averagehandler extends FunctionHandler {
    @Override
    protected boolean isConditionMet(Function function) {
        return function instanceof Average;
    }

    @Override
    protected void calculate(Function function) {
        // do average stuff
    }
}

public class SumHandler extends FunctionHandler {
    @Override
    protected boolean isConditionMet(Function function) {
        return function instanceof Sum;
    }

    @Override
    protected void calculate(Function function) {
        // do sum stuff
    }
}

public class MaxHandler extends FunctionHandler {
    @Override
    protected boolean isConditionMet(Function function) {
        return function instanceof Max;
    }

    @Override
    protected void calculate(Function function) {
        // do max stuff
    }
}
```

now look for a nice central place to put your chain together (e.g. a utility class)

```
public final class FunctionUtil {
    public static final FunctionHandler HANDLER;

    static {
        HANDLER = new Averagehandler();
        HANDLER.setNexthandler(new SumHandler()).setNexthandler(new MaxHandler());
    }
}
```

now you can start replacing your if-else-blocks with calls to `FunctionUtil.HANDLER.handleFunction(function);`

Comment: thanks, Macro, however, I just looked at your suggestion, I couldn't quite understand why we need to introduce the chain of responsibility to this problem? Isn't just using each handler object to handle each function enough ?  E.g.
I was thinking it would be something like this if using this kind of approach

Comment: a single handler would be enough. the chain of responsibility frees you from the decision which handler is the right for the `Function` object at hand. it simply takes the object and passes it to the handlers unless one is the right to handle the actual type of function