# Eliminating a conditional statement with instanceOf checks

Tags: refactoring, instanceof, visitor-pattern

I have the following method:

```
@Override
public <T> T method(T object){
    if(object instanceOf Type1){
    ...
    }
    elseif(object instanceOf Type2){
    ...
    }
    ...
}
```

`object` is always of type `SuperType` and `Type1`, `Type2`, ... are all subtypes of `SuperType`. I don't have acces to any of the types `SuperType`, `Type1`, etc., so I cannot change them.

I´d like to eliminate this structure that has a lot of `if`-s and `instanceOf` checks. I tried implementing the Visitor pattern for this purpose, but it didn´t work, as I cannot modify any of the types mentioned above.

Does anyone know a nice solution for this example? Thank you!

Comment: Does not avoid the `instanceof`, but if `object` is always of type `SuperType` you should probably declare `<T extends SuperType>`.

Comment: The method is an overridden version of a type I don't have access to, the method signature should stay the same.

Comment: Related reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665898/when-if-else-instance-of-are-inevitable-how-do-we-improve-the-design-apart?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a dispatch table.

```
private final static Map<Class<?>, Handler> dispatch = ....
// contains things like  Type2.class -> Type2Handler

dispatch.get(object.getClass()).handle(object);
// may need to iterate superclasses if that is a concern
```

Not sure if that is better, though.

Comment: It seems to be somewhat easier to maintain at least :)